# Can't Import ArcPy module into Rodeo

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

I am using Rodeo as my Python IDE for data analysis, and I'm trying to import the ArcPy module in Rodeo. However, when I attempt to import it, I receive the error "No module named 'arcpy.'"

I think it may be an issue of Rodeo wanting to use the built-in Python, but I'd like to have it use the Python executable that ships with ArcGIS (I'm using ArcGIS 10.5).

Can I use the ArcPy module in Rodeo?

Comment: You will have to change the python path and point it to you arcgis python instance. It is usually located at c: /python27/arcgis10.5/python.exe.  http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/#changing-your-python-path

Comment: @Thomas that looks suitable to offer as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I've set the python path to my arcgis python instance (C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.5/python.exe), and the Use Built-In Python option has been set to "No". But when I make these changes, I receive the message: "Missing package: Jupyter," and I'm unable to run any processes from the Rodeo terminal.

Comment: You will need to install the Jupyter package into arcgis python instance. Try using pip: c:/python27/arcgis10.5/scrpits/pip.exe install jupyter

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, that was what I needed! I have now imported the ArcPy module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some trouble following the comments above, therefore i will try to provide a more concise answer using @Thomas' suggestion.

First go to `preferences -> Python command -> change the directory to your ArcGIS location (as seen in photo)`

[image]

Next, open the command prompt and type in `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\Scripts\pip.exe install jupyter` this should install the dependencies for Rodeo to run in the correct folder. Make sure that you have the correct path as the version `ArcGIS10.6` may differ.